# pickle.load: ImportError: No module named k_means_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm dumping a `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` object using `pickle` like this:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=7)

kmeans.fit(X)

pickle.dump(kmeans, open(model_fname, "w"), protocol=2)
```

However, if I try to reload this pickle file:

```
if os.path.exists(model_fname):
    print "Loading existing model .."
    return pickle.load(open(model_fname, "rb"))
```

I'm getting:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named k_means_
```

How can I load this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replaced `pickle` by `joblib`:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```